# Half-power of second derivative operator

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators, fractional-calculus

I'm studying fractional powers of an operator and came across an exercise I could not solve.

> Let $A: D(A)\subset L^2(0,\pi) \to L^2(0,\pi)$ be a linear operator defined by
>   \begin{gather*}
> D(A) = H^2(0,\pi) \cap H_0^1(0,\pi) \\
> Au = -u_{xx}
> \end{gather*}
>
> How do I prove that $A^{\frac{1}{2}}u = iu_x$?

A bit of context: I am actually trying to prove that
\begin{equation*}
\|u_x\|_{L^2(0,\pi)} \leq \|Au\|_{L^2(0,\pi)}^{\frac{1}{2}}\|u\|_{L^2(0,\pi)}^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation*}

I do know that this will fairly simply come from the Momentum Inequality 
\begin{equation}
\|A^\alpha u\|_{L^2(0,\pi)} \leq K\|Au\|_{L^2(0,\pi)}^\alpha\|u\|_{L^2(0,\pi)}^{1-\alpha} \quad,\quad 0 \leq \alpha \leq 1
\end{equation}
but I am struggling to prove that $A^{\frac{1}{2}}u = iu_x$. Intuitively, I know it should be true, but the calculations are not leading me anywhere. Perhaps I am missing something basic here?

Comment: Maybe I am just being naive here, but if $T(f) = i f'$, then isn't $T(T(f))= -f''$ just by linearity of the derivative.?

Comment: $A^{1/2}$ is not going to be $iu_{x}$ because of the domain condition that, in effect, forces $u(0)=u(\pi)=0$.

Comment: Hmm, thinking better (with a rested mind), I guess it should only be true if $u \in D(A)$, which for my purposes should be good enough. Then @irchans answer should apply.

Comment: $A^{1/2}$ is going to be positive. However $iu_x$ is not. You can use a Fourier $\sin$ expansion to handle it.